# Почему родинки называют родинками?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а почему темные пятнышки на коже называют родинками? Ведь далеко не всегда с ними рождаются (у меня, например, родинки появляются и исчезаю самопроизвольно))).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У кровных родственников родинки часто оказываются в одном и том же месте, и форму имеют примерно одинаковую так что по ним родню определить даже возможно. Потому и "родинка", что о родне знак.

Answer (score 0):

Родинка - от "родимый". Стяжение от "родимое пятно"
Прямой связи с "род", "родня" тут нет, только с "родовой", "роды".

Про одинаковые родимые пятна у родни - это вряд ли. Более правдоподобной еще можно признать  версию, что по родинкам и пятнам можно было найти и опознать своего ребенка или родственника. Но это тоже, видимо, надумано.

Что касается самопроизвольно появляющихся и исчезающих родинок, то речь, видимо, идет о так называемых пигментных пятнах, которые родинками иногда называют просто по какой-то частной традиции.